# Varnish Cache Invalidate by Timestamp

Tags: varnish

Is there a way to clear varnish cache by timestamp. I want to remove all the caches responses from yesterday or from any specific timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is an `obj.age` variable in VCL, it's not accessible from the `ban()` function in Varnish versions older than 6.2. This currently also includes our 6.0 LTS version.

### Insert timestamp in the cache as response header

One way to approach this problem is by inserting a timestamp in a custom header at insertion time.

Here's some example VCL where we assign the current UNIX timestamp to the `time` response header:

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;

sub vcl_backend_response {
  set beresp.http.time = std.real2integer(std.time2real(now,0),0);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  unset resp.http.time;
}
```

By assigning this value in `sub vcl_backend_response`, we're ensuring that this value is stored in the cached object as part of the response headers.

### Matching the timestamp in the ban expression

Any response header can be matched by the `ban()` function. But since `ban()` has no `>` or `<` operators, we'll have to use a regular expression.

When testing, one of my objects had `1636103641` as its timestamp. The current timestamp was `1636103870`, which means the object in cache was `229` seconds old.

I created the following regular expression:

```
^1636103[7-8][0-9]{2}$
```

This matches all timestamps between `1636103700` and `1636103899`, which is a 199 second range, based on the current timestamp.

By **NOT** matching this pattern, older timestamps would be selected and that's in fact the trick.

I ended up using the following ban command to match old objects:

```
varnishadm ban obj.http.time '!~ ^1636103[7-8][0-9]{2}$'
```

### Customizing the regex to your needs

> Before banning, make sure the custom header containing the timestamp is added to your VCL code. This custom header will be matched in your `ban` command.

Based on your needs, take the current UNIX timestamp, calculate the range you want to match and create a regex that does an *inverse match*.

### Matching obj.age as of Varnish 6.2

If you're using Varnish 6.2 or newer, you can simply run the following ban command:

```
varnishadm ban obj.age '> 1d'
```

This will remove all objects  that have been in the cache for more than a day.